# Does a foreach loop copy each item of an IEnumerable while iterating?

Tags: c#, foreach, ienumerable

I have a `foreach` loop like below

```
        foreach (XYZ split in this.splits )
        {
            // this code is inserted for debug purpose only
            bool check = object.ReferenceEquals(splits.First(), split);
            .....
        }
```

When I have single element in `this.splits`, check is returning false. I have checked by some other way, check is always returning false. Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depends on the way the enumerator is implemented. The implementation is free to return a copy or the object itself. In fact, it can return whatever it likes; for instance, `Enumerable.Range` returns a sequence of numbers and none of the elements are actually stored anywhere. They are generated on the fly. If the return type is a value-type, it's certainly a copy of something.

Also, nothing requires the object to return the same sequence each time `GetEnumerator` is called on it. In your code example, it does it once in `foreach` and another time when you call `.First`. These sequences are not required to be equivalent.

Comment: Thanks man. I quickly checked the place where the IEnumarable was created and this what I found


from rec in recs select new XYZ(rec)

Thanks again for ur help.